# AngularJS Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router (only in IE browser)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-ui-router, cross-browser

I am new to AngularJS and having an **error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router**. This issue only occur in ***IE browser*** and haven't encounter any problems when using other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Please see this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UArad.png) to view the error screenshot.

Here's my code:

**HTML CODE:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, IE=11, chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/jkg-browser-logo-32@3x.ico">
        <title>Test</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <!-- angularjs -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.19/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- main links -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sass/main.css">
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controller/mainController.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="maintenance.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
        <!--MAIN_CONTENT-->
        <main ui-view></main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js CODE:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/home');
    
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .state('menu', {
        url:'/menu',
        templateUrl: 'views/menu.html'
    });
    
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Can someone help me resolve this and explain why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: version of IE..?

Comment: i'm using IE 11

Comment: Try moving scripts file at the bottom of body tag ....It might be because of ordering .

Comment: the issue still occur after moving all script files at the bottom. I also tried moving only `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` and `<script src="js/controller/mainController.js"></script>` but no luck at all.